# Getting a variable to outer scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm confused by this one. First of all this is my code:

```
router.post('/update', (req, res, next) => {
  // Todo legit credit card holding
  Account.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    {
      $set: {
        // username: req.body.username,
        creditCardNo: req.body.cardNo,
        isPremium: true,
      },
    },
    { upsert: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
  var newUser;
  Account.findById(req.user._id,(err, doc)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      newUser = doc;
    }
  });
  console.log(newUser);
  res.render('user-pannel/pannel', {
    title: 'User pannel',
    user: newUser,
  });
});
```

What it does is: It gets the POST call and updates a record in the db. Now I want to basically reload the the page (res.render part) and send the new user object.

I need to send the new one, because the one in `req.user` is now outdated (was updated before and I'm just printing the old version).

I tried getting around the problem by doing this `newUser = doc;`, but for some reason the `newUser`variable is undefined when logged outside of the `findById` method. Why? If I console log the doc inside of the `findById` method, it returns the changed object.

Comment: you should put your render method inside the callback of your findById

Comment: Oh. Yes. That works. Thank you. Is there any way to get it outside of the scope though? Maybe return it out?

Comment: Is the POST from a form post or from an Ajax call?  If from a form post, then `res.render()` (when positioned properly in your code) will update the page in the browser.  But, if it's an Ajax call, then you will need to do something in the client code to cause the page to change.

Comment: No.  T'he ONLY place that `doc` is known is INSIDE that callback.  This is asynchronous code.  That means the rest of your code runs BEFORE `doc` is available in the callback so the ONLY place to use it is inside the callback.

Comment: you can do it by moving to synchronous using `async/await`

Comment: If you want to extract the value for use outside, the usual solution would be to create a Promise that resolves with the value you want. Then, in the outer scope, you can do `myPromise.then(val => /* do stuff with val */ );`

Comment: Oooooh. Ok thanks! If someone wants to just put it all together so I could pick it as best answer please go ahead. Otherwise I'll just do it in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned it into an async function and `await`ed its resolution with the desired value.

```js
router.post('/update', async (req, res, next) => {
  // Todo legit credit card holding
  Account.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    {
      $set: {
        // username: req.body.username,
        creditCardNo: req.body.cardNo,
        isPremium: true,
      },
    },
    { upsert: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
  const newUser = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Account.findById(req.user._id,(err, doc) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(doc);
    });
  });
  console.log(newUser);
  res.render('user-pannel/pannel', {
    title: 'User pannel',
    user: newUser,
  });
});
```